# Problem about house/building etc building time passing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Got into a problem and i can't seem to find the issue. I am currently making a war based game where players are able to buy certain buildings and place them wherever they want. When they choose the spot they like it starts building. After specific time passes it finishes building and it appears in the spot.
**THE PROBLEM:** I can't figure out how to give the building time to buildings if there are more than one of them building. I tried arrays, but it came to nothing.
**THE CODE:** The code is kind of hard to read. But if it helps, here you go:

```
public void BuyBuilding(string whichBuilding)
    {
        if (whichBuilding == "CIV")
        {
            if (CIVQUANT < MaxCivQuant && decidedNotToBuy == false && howManyAreBuilding < 4)
            {
                if (ELEM.Money >= 10000) //IF ENOUGH MONEY
                {
                    howManyAreBuilding++;
                    whichBuildBought[howManyAreBuilding] = whichBuilding;
                }
```

^ Here i made a method that activates whenever a player presses a button, it checks which building it is `"CIV"` is one of them, i removes 10k from the player's currency (Not shown here for now)and adds a `"CIV"` value to a `whichBuildBought` string array. Then we go to update where the game is checking if any building was bought:

```
private void Update()
    {
    if (boughtBuildingS == true && whichBuildBought[howManyAreBuilding] == "CIV")
        {
            ElapsedTimeCalculator(howManyAreBuilding);
            if (elapsedTime[howManyAreBuilding] == time.OnDayChanged)
            {
                elapsedTime[howManyAreBuilding] = 0;
                boughtBuildingTime[howManyAreBuilding] = 0;
                ElapsedTimeCalculatorPassed = false;
                howManyAreBuilding--;
            }
        }
```

^ Here i activate an `ElapsedTimeCalculator` method shown below, `Time.OnDayChanged` is a day counter, i use it to check if the day the player bought the building matches the day it's supposed to finish building by giving `boughtBuildingTime` specific array value a current day value and then giving `elapsedTime` array that value plus how many days its supposed to be building. In the update method if the `elapsedTime` of that specific building in the array is done it just finished building and some extra things happen that i just removed for now.

```
public void ElapsedTimeCalculator(int i)
    {
        if (ElapsedTimeCalculatorPassed == false && whichBuildBought[i] == "CIV")
        {
            boughtBuildingTime[i] = time.OnDayChanged;
            elapsedTime[i] = boughtBuildingTime[i] + 20;
            ElapsedTimeCalculatorPassed = true;
        }
```

Thanks in advance for helping! Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what isn't working as desired in your code? If you're having trouble matching multiple buildings to different build times, have you tried other kinds of collections, perhaps a Dictionary?

Comment: @Serlite Since it's a war based game i have a timer script that just controls time, like 24 hours 30 days 365 days, years etc. Each time a player buys a building and places it in the desired spot it starts to build once the time has been unpaused (ElapsedTimeCalculator starts to work). This code works with one building, but i can't find a solution if i want more than one building to be building at the same time.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to keep track of a variety of information for each new building started (name, time remaining, etc). When you encounter scenarios like this, it can be a sign that you need to create a new class. Create a list of that class as the building queue for each player. Each time the game progresses, iterate through all items in that array and reduce the time remaining. When it reaches 0 for any item, remove that item and perform whatever actions you do for a completed building.